# IHttpHandler to redirect "https://example.com" to "https://www.example.com"?

Tags: asp.net

I use IIS7's `HTTP Redirect` feature to redirect http://example.com requests to http://www.example.com but this feature cannot be used in this way with `https` protocol.

Is it possible to use `IHttpHandler` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use IIS7, you might want to try URL Rewrite Module.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203216/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072810-1.aspx

http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/